# When to use SproutCore and When Ember

Tags: ember.js, sproutcore

I am about to develop a web application, and I need an MVC framework for the same, I started working with the SproutCore, but doing a few more research, I came to know about Ember.js also. I have seen a lot of post, where they are claiming that ember.js is much better than Sproutcore, but looking at the differences, I have seen that the widget support is not there in Ember.js.

I have seen some other post for differnces also between the two like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425307/differences-between-sproutcore-and-ember), but I am still not getting it, when to prefer Sproutcore and when Ember.

Answer (score 3):

It predominantly comes down to the design style of application you are after as technically there are many similarities because of their shared ancestry.

If you want a web application that 'feels' like a Desktop app I'd go for Sproutcore.

If you want your web application to be something more like Twitter, github or stackoverflow I'd go for Ember.

Answer (score 0):

According to my history knowledge, sproutcore is the predecessor of emberjs.

Comment: Emberjs has forked Sproutocre, but both the projects are active.